# Is it wise to develop a prototype GUI before designing other part of the system?

Tags: java, user-interface

Is it wise to develop a prototype GUI before designing other part of the system?

I am using Java for this small project. It will be a program with GUI and database connection. Say the database has table A and B, the user can choose which table to interact with. The program then display the contents of, say, table A in the GUI, and allows the user to change the content and submit the changes, or delete, or insert.

Comment: Yes, why not. The GUI may drive part of the design. Mhh Anyway I think this question is subjective.

Comment: Why close vote? It's directly related to SDLC. We should see what are all the approaches are, and what are the justification for that. Since when a healthy discussion subject became a candidate for close vote?

Answer (score 7):

I think GUI should be developed first before any back-end development starts. There are couple of reason to do this:

- You gain clarity on how model objects should interact.
- Usability poses lots of restrictions on the way you want to pull data. You will probably want to develop and architect after you're 100% sure what constraints are there.
- On business point, managers like to have a dumb function UI before any development start. Many times, the feedback leads in major changes in back-end assumptions. Which is a lot less pain than the case when you get a change request *after* the back-end development is over.

My personal experience goes that simultaneous development of GUI and back-end is a bit messy. Plus GUI provides solid expectation of behavior from back-end. Moreover, this approach makes sure all the developers, your client and your manager on the same page.

Comment: +1 especially the part that showing the GUI often uncovers flaws in the analysis.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Joel Spolsky that it is a great idea to write a [functional spec](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000036.html) before writing code. Part of that spec should include a collection of screen mockups. @O.D. is right, [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/) is a great tool. It has saved me a lot of time in the past.

Once you have a functional spec in place that the business users are happy with, you will then have a better idea of how to design your system to meet the requirements. e.g. is high performance a requirement, domain model vs simple crud etc.

Then you should start by taking a single use case and building a vertical slice of your application. Build a GUI, service layer, persistence layer, database schema in one iteration. This will hopefully point out any problems with your design and give you the chance to modify it before you start building out the horizontal functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say yes and no.

No because you should design you application to be modularized enough so that your logic and data do not depend on UI design.

Yes because it is always smart to design everything before you actually start implementing it.

So what I mean is that you should make a concept, but not let your UI concept 'tie your hands' when you implement your logic. So if your managers clients don't like your conceptual UI, you can always change it without actually changing your application logic.

Answer (score 1):

Well showing you GUI brfore starting to program is a very a good Idea, specially that you enable the enduser (Customer) to check if the UI is up to his expectations, which can save you lots of time.

In order to do that you dont necessarily need to develope a "real" prototype, you can use programms which enable you to fast design the UI of your App, including a minimal workflow simulation instead of full funcionality.

i had a very good experience with: [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/) can really recommend it

Answer (score 0):

Writing spec before your code is always a good idea, because it makes you think. But most specs I have seen are not that good. And if the spec is too technical, users will at the end sign-off your spec without really understanding what are they going to get.

I have seen best results when either presenting the User Manual to the client, or by discussing mockups of the system one scenario at a time.

Note that half-baked mockups won't do the trick. You need your mockups to be fully populated with relevant data (Ever tried to discuss some screens with accounting while the numbers on the screen don't match? There's no way at all you could explain to them these are only dummy numbers...)

And the caveat of using mockups is that users will more often than not believe the app is "almost finished", whatever you do or say. It must be some subconscious thing, I'm not sure.  But to avoid that, most of specialized tools have either only "black&white" look and feel or multiple skins you can switch to and from.

There is a pretty complete list of mockup tools here. Many of them are free:
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools

My own tool is pretty popular: http://MockupScreens.com, I created it a long time ago exactly because of my own frustration with above mentioned problems.